# Why does opening /proc/cpuinfo take 17 ms?

Tags: proc

Running this

```
strace -ff -tt perl -e 'open(A,"<","/proc/cpuinfo");'
```

gives this:

```
22:36:10.365187 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/cpuinfo", O_RDONLY) = 3
22:36:10.382061 ioctl(3, TCGETS, 0x7fffb127ea50) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
```

`/proc/cpuinfo` is an in-memory file that does not require access to a slow disk. Why is it taking 17 ms to open?

I have tested 10 times on an idle system and the timing is very consistent.

```
$ uname -a
Linux hk 4.15.0-20-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 24 06:16:15 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: /proc contents are not in-memory files.  They're a means to communicate with the kernel and devices.

Comment: I'm no expert on syscalls, but opening itself doesn't take so long - `openat` already returns fd 3 at the timestamp listed. Likely there's something else going on. Wild guess would be that the process is put on hold by the CPU itself and other processes are taken care of in the mean time.  I'd guess if you set priority/niceness value higher you'd see decrease  in the time

Comment: Hint: `-T` option shows time durations of syscalls. Also, I've reproduced this on Linux kernel 5.1.9: `openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/cpuinfo", O_RDONLY) = 3 <0.016822>` - 17 msec.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since version 4.12 of the kernel, on x86 CPUs with support for [the APERF / MPERF MSRs](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=f8475cef90082bf0902ddab106112de130d90395), there’s a slight delay when opening `/proc/cpuinfo` to ensure that the CPU frequencies are accurately reported (or at least, don’t show values which are too stale). This was changed slightly in [cpufreq: x86: Make scaling_cur_freq behave more as expected](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=4815d3c56d1e10449a44089a47544d9ba84fad0d) (4.13, with increased delays) and again in [x86 / CPU: Always show current CPU frequency in /proc/cpuinfo](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=7d5905dc14a87805a59f3c5bf70173aac2bb18f8) (4.14, with reduced delays).

Comment: That looks about right. This is only slow the in the first round: `for t in {1..100}; do time cat /proc/cpuinfo >/dev/null;sleep 0.99;done`